# BigCommerce Hello World app - using app in the store

Tags: javascript, jwt, bigcommerce

I installed successfully the [Hello World app](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-ruby-sinatra).

I'm trying to use the app in the storefront.
Following the instructions, I added the code provided to the script manager :

```
<script>
var appClientId = "**BC_CLIENT_ID**"; // TODO: Fill this in with your app's client ID.
var storeHash = "**TEST_STORE_HASH**"; // TODO: Fill this in wit the test store's store hash (found in base url before the `store-` part)
var appUrl = "**APP_URL**"; // TODO: Replace this with the URL to your app.

// Get the JWT token from the BC server signed first.
$.get('/customer/current.jwt?app_client_id=' + appClientId, function(jwtToken) {
    // Now that we have the JWT token, use it to get the recent purchases block.
    $.get(appUrl + '/storefront/' + storeHash + '/customers/' + jwtToken + '/recently_purchased.html', function(htmlContent) {
        $('#recent_purchases_block').html(htmlContent, true);
    });
});
</script>
```

I first ran into a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error, which I solved including jquery-3.3.1.

But then, I get a 404 error with the GET request. I tried different values for **APP_URL**, but still get this error.
Here is the GET request :
https://www.marineff.com/rebates/load/storefront/STORE_HASH/customers/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJjdXN0b21lciI6eyJpZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJqam9yaW9AaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJncm91cF9pZCI6IjAifSwiaXNzIjoiYmMvYXBwcyIsInN1YiI6Imt6N3Nma20yZHgiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTE5NDI5NTEsImV4cCI6MTU1MTk0Mzg1MSwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiYXVkIjoiNGZocWNvOTBha21qMzI5Z2lmMXY4dzFqdzRqN3FzZyIsImFwcGxpY2F0aW9uX2lkIjoiNGZocWNvOTBha21qMzI5Z2lmMXY4dzFqdzRqN3FzZyIsInN0b3JlX2hhc2giOiJrejdzZmttMmR4Iiwib3BlcmF0aW9uIjoiY3VycmVudF9jdXN0b21lciJ9.i7mguILu_jGue9nO5wZbtG8IhXqFkKuY71fAEsZTe27Tyxfjm4SAhUZUUxNvTbVhADP4Qm9kqY6BjU7I-SDgWA/recently_purchased.html

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: The appUrl variable should be the URL where the Hello World app is hosted. Where is the app currently? Are you working locally or is the app hosted somewhere like Heroku?

Comment: I changed appUrl to the directory where the app is hosted and it is working. Thanks!
Actually, I tried earlier this option, BUT, the url in the var declaration should be written without the last "/" in order to work, like this :
var appUrl = "https://myhost.com/rebates";

Comment: Nice! Glad you were able to get it working :)